# Arduino + Django REST API + Cloud Run = HTTP 302 + No response

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, arduino, iot, google-cloud-run

I am exploring the wonderful world of IOT, just started.

I wanted to start simple:

- Arduino Rev2 Wifi, combined with couple of sensors (humidity, temp etc)
- Django REST API, to push mentioned data, deployed on Cloud Run (MySQL is somewhere else)
- Some kinda of BI e.g. Looker on gcp etc.

I assume that this may not be the go-to architecture but i tried nevertheless :)

Django works fine

This is the view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from server.models import Reading, Sensor


@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse(False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print(request)
        temperature = request.POST.get("temperature")
        humidity = request.POST.get("humidity")
        heatIndex = request.POST.get("heatIndex")
        sensorId = request.POST.get("sensorId")
        print(sensorId, temperature, humidity, heatIndex)
        currentSensor = Sensor.objects.get(pk=sensorId)

        new_reading = Reading.objects.create(
            temperature=temperature,
            humidity=humidity,
            heatIndex=heatIndex,
            sensor=currentSensor
        )

        return HttpResponse(True)

    else:
        return HttpResponse(False)
```

I can easly push data via Postman and check either via admin panel or MySql workbench that those data were correctly saved.

With Arduino is not that simple.

```
#include "DHT.h"
#include "WiFiNINA.h"
#include "arduino_secrets.h"
#include "SPI.h"


#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define DHTPIN 12

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

float val;
int redPin = 2;
int greenPin = 7;


char ssid[] = SECRET_WIFINAME;
char pass[] = SECRET_WIFIPASS;
char serv[] = SECRET_SERVER;


int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
String postData;
String tempVariable = "temperature=";
String humidVariable = "&humidity=";
String heatVariable = "&heatIndex=";
String sensorIdVariable = "&sensorId=1";
String postText;


WiFiClient client;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  // init diodes
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);

  //init sensor
  dht.begin();
  delay(2000);

  //init wifi

  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to Network named: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    delay(10000);
  }

  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  IPAddress gateway = WiFi.gatewayIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);
}


void loop() {


  //getting sensor data
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);
  float hic = dht.computeHeatIndex(t, h, false);

  postData = tempVariable + t + humidVariable + h + heatVariable + hic + sensorIdVariable;


  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
    digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
    return;
  } else {

    digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
  }




  while (client.available()) {

    char c = client.read();

    Serial.write(c);
  }



  if (client.connect(serv, 80)) {
    Serial.println(client);
    Serial.println("connected to server");


    client.println("POST / HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: (delated)");
    client.println("User-Agent: ArduinoWiFi/1.1");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(postData.length());
    client.println();
    client.print(postData);
    delay(10000);


  }



  else {

    // if you couldn't make a connection:

    Serial.println("connection failed");
    digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
  }


  //  while (client.available()) {
  char c = client.read();
  Serial.write(c);
  // }



  if (client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("connection closed");
    client.stop();
  }





  delay(10000);
}
```

I am connecting to Wifi no problem but when this thing runs, i get no response from the server. It shows that it connected successfully but the response is empty.
On GCP logs, I can see that those requests had HTTP 302 but they did not run Django and did not give response. Just 302..

Any ideas what more could be tested?

p.s. arduino_secrets:
#define SECRET_SERVER "http://....

Thanks :)

From the server side, i tried pushing the data via URL and later changed to push data via body of the request. No different from Postman perspective.

From Arduino i tried changing client.connect 80 or ssl 443, no difference.
Later i changed the url between https, http, added WWW, no difference.

I tried adding and substracting various param from http request, like Connection: Close, etc. No difference.

I may have had a minute, where i got the response from server in arduino ide, when i made the http badly but not sure how i did it.

Comment: HTTP 302 (FOUND) is a response. The response is saying I cannot answer your request, go here and ask again. Look at the HTTP headers for the "Location" header. That is the URL to resend the request.

Comment: Hello John. Yes, thats a good hint :) This is what ChatGPT told me when i described the issue. Nevertheless, i spend an hour trying to get the header in Arduino (with ChatGPT code), still did not manage. It gave me bad code... will try again later.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody will ever encounter this question, I managed to make this work.

About that 302... Cloud Run forces every website to be https. If you ask it via http, it will redirect. Arduino has problems with redirecting (not confirmed), it does not follow redirects. This means, that you have to use ssl.
This is a working example:

```
#include "DHT.h"
#include "WiFiNINA.h"
#include "arduino_secrets.h"
#include "SPI.h"


#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define DHTPIN 12

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

float val;
int redPin = 2;
int greenPin = 7;


char ssid[] = SECRET_WIFINAME;
char pass[] = SECRET_WIFIPASS;
char serv[] = SECRET_SERVER;


int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
String postData;
String tempVariable = "temperature=";
String humidVariable = "&humidity=";
String heatVariable = "&heatIndex=";
String sensorIdVariable = "&sensorId=1";
String postText;

//server required SSL, if ever not needed, change  this to WifiClient and port to 80. 
// if this app does not work, try to update firmware first. Later, try to upload ssl cert.
WiFiSSLClient client;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  // init diodes
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);

  //init sensor
  dht.begin();
  delay(2000);

  //init wifi
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to Network named: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    delay(10000);
  }

  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  IPAddress gateway = WiFi.gatewayIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);
}


void loop() {

  //getting sensor data
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);
  float hic = dht.computeHeatIndex(t, h, false);

  // combining gathered data into post data
  postData = tempVariable + t + humidVariable + h + heatVariable + hic + sensorIdVariable;


  //checking if recieved data is ok or nok
  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
    digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
    return;
  } else {

    digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
  }



  //was the board connected so far?
  while (client.available()) {

    char c = client.read();

    Serial.write(c);
  }


  //connect to server and post data
  if (client.connect(serv, 443)) {
    Serial.println(client);
    Serial.println("connected to server");


    client.println("POST / HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: " + String(SECRET_SERVER));
    client.println("User-Agent: ArduinoWiFi/1.1");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(postData.length());
    client.println();
    client.print(postData);
    delay(10000);


  }



  else {

    // if you couldn't make a connection:

    Serial.println("connection failed");
    digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
  }


  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }



  if (client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("connection closed");
    client.stop();
  }





  delay(60000);
}
```

Posting data via params or body matters but rather from server side, Django reads those two differently.  WiFiSSLClient and port 443 what had to be changed mostly.

I also did have issues with SECRET_SERVER. I had "https://myurl.com". I tried many iterations of this variable. What worked was just "myurl.com" without any addition.

I also managed to make this working on LAN. To do this:
Run Django on your laptop:

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

read your local IP via cmd, ipconfig (e.g. 127.0.0.22)

Arduino:
Change SECRET_SERVER to that 127.0.0.22 and port (Django port!) 8000. Not sure if standard http 80 will work.

```
...client.connect(serv, 8000)
```

Change back to http, i.e.

```
WiFiClient
```

Cheers :)

Github: https://github.com/PDymala/ArduinoExperiments/tree/main/AirSensorWithServer